# Does `$.when().done()` evaluate its arguments upon execution?

Tags: jquery

I have the following code which may not be doing what I want.

```
function ajaxTempOff(f) {
    $.ajaxSetup({
        async: false
    });
    f();
    $.ajaxSetup({
        async: true
    });
}

function setAuthenticated() {
    ajaxTempOff(function() {
        $.when(
            $.getJSON(window.url_root + '/show/')
        ).done(function(data) {
            window.authenticated = data['is_user_authenticated'];
        });
    });

    return window.authenticated;
}
```

Is the JSON call executed synchronously in this case? Or can the function return before the `$.getJSON`is done?

Comment: what are you trying to do here?

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.when/  Absolutely not. `.done()` is fired off only if the `$.getJSON` returns a successful state.

Comment: If you turn off `async`, there's not much reason to use `.when()` or `.done()`...

Comment: You're misusing `$.when`. Just use `$.getJSON(window.url_root + '/show/').then(...)`. `when` is for grouping multiple deferreds.

Answer (score 0):

In any case, the expression supplied to `$.when` as its *argument* will be evaluated immediately. It's just how JS works.

This case is interesting, however. It's told in `$.ajaxSetup` [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajaxSetup/):

> All subsequent Ajax calls using any function will use the new
>   settings, unless overridden by the individual calls, until the next
>   invocation of $.ajaxSetup().

So that's what happens here:

- `async` is set to `false` globally first,
- anonymous function passed to `ajaxTempOff` is executed then, step by step
- in this function, `$.when()` call evaluates `$.getJSON` expression with the *current* setting of `async` - which is `false` at this point, so the request is synchronous
- immediately after it's resolved (and it's immediately after in this case indeed - as the request *is* blocking), it fires `.done()` part
- after that, all the lines written below `.when().done()` chain will be executed

The bottom line is that `setAuthenticated` will return a value set by getJSON call in this case.

I've created a similar [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TkVxU/), with the key part modified for clarity:

```
function setAuthenticated() {
    ajaxTempOff(function() {
        $.when(
            $.getJSON('/echo/json/')
        ).done(function(data) {
            console.log('Done');
            window.answer = 42;
        });
        console.log('Return');
    });
    return window.answer;
}
console.log( setAuthenticated() );
```

It's easy to verify that if this function is invoked as a callback passed to `ajaxTempOff`, 'Done' will be printed *before* 'Return', and the final record will be 42 - because that's, you know, the answer. )

But if you run this function as is (or just comment out that 'async':false setting, 'Return' will be printed first, `undefined` (the result value of `setAuthenticated` dealing with non-blocking requests) - next, and only after that the request will actually be submitted to the server. Finally, `Done` will appear in the log.